# Trying to create a date from a string in Racket - find-seconds VERY slow, week-day year-day required?

Tags: datetime, racket

I'm trying to parse dates from a large csv file in Racket.

The most straightforward way to do this would be to create a new `date` struct.  But it requires the `week-day` and `year-day` parameters.  Of course I don't have these, and this seems like a real weakness of the `date` module that I don't understand.

So, as an alternative, I decided to use `find-seconds` to convert the raw date vals into seconds and then pass that to `seconds->date`.  This works, but is brutally slow.

```
(time
 (let loop ([n 10000])
   (apply find-seconds '(0 0 12 1 1 2012)) ; this takes 3 seconds for 10000
   ;(date 0 0 12 1 1 2012 0 0 #f 0) ; this is instant
   (if (zero? n)
       'done
       (loop (sub1 n)))))
```

`find-seconds` takes 3 seconds to do 10000 values, and I have several million.  Creating the `date` struct is of course instant, but I don't have the week-day, year-day values.

My questions are:

1.) Why is `week-day`/`year-day` required for creating date structs?

2.) Is `find-seconds` supposed to be this slow (ie, bug)?  Or am I doing something wrong?

3.) Are there any alternatives to parse dates in a fast manner.  I know `srfi/19` has a `string->date` function, but I'd then have to change everything to use that module's struct instead of racket's built-in one.  And it may suffer the same performance hit of find-seconds, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although not documented as such, it appears that `week-day` and `year-day` are "no-ops" when using the `date` struct with `date->seconds`. If I set them both to 0, a `date->seconds` doesn't complain. I suspect it ignores them:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/date)

(define d (date 1    ;sc
                2    ;mn
                3    ;hr
                20   ;day
                8    ;month
                2012 ;year
                0    ;weekday  <<<
                0    ;year-day <<<
                #f   ;dst?
                0    ;time-zone-offset
                ))

(displayln (seconds->date (date->seconds d)))

;; =>
#(struct:date* 1 2 3 20 8 2012 1 232 #t -14400 0 EDT)
                               ^ ^^^
```

My guess is that the `date` struct was defined for use with `seconds->date`, where `week-day` and `year-day` would be interesting information to provide. Then for `date->seconds`, rather than define another struct with those fields missing (they're "redundant" for determining the date, which is why you're understandably annoyed :)) for use with `date->seconds`, the same struct was reused.

Does that help? It's not clear to me from your question what you're trying to do with the date information from the CSV. If you want to convert it to an integer `seconds` value, I think the above should work for you. If you have something else in mind, perhaps you could explain.

Comment: Thanks Greg.  I'll test when I get home, but I think you've solved it for me.  :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say this is an oversight in `racket/date`.

The call to `find-seconds` is expensive because it needs to search to find the number of seconds. And since you only need to know the week-day it an unnecessary computation.

Write to the mailing list in order to get advice.